# Send and read the button state via CAN bus using Arduino

Tags: button, arduino, interrupt, can-bus

I'm intending to read the change of button input using 2 separate Arduino that connected via CAN bus (MP2515). The transmitter will connect to button with internal pulldown resistor, that pin will act as external interrupt. My reference is coming from [here](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/please-help-with-a-simple-code-send-can-bus-message-with-button-press/635873/6). By not assign any value to data frame (canMsg1 and canMsg2 in the code below), is that enough for the receiver to understand the input pin state?

The origin code using `digitalRead(pin)` to read and later write state of the button by single Arduino.

transmitter of CAN massage

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <mcp2515.h>

struct can_frame canMsg1;
struct can_frame canMsg2;

MCP2515 mcp2515(10);

int incPin(2);
int decPin(3);
unsigned long current_time = 0;
unsigned long previous_time = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SPI.begin();

  mcp2515.reset();
  mcp2515.setBitrate(CAN_500KBPS, MCP_8MHZ);
  mcp2515.setNormalMode();
  
  canMsg1.can_id = 0xAA;
  canMsg1.can_dlc = 1;
  canMsg2.can_id = 0xBB
  canMsg2.can_dlc = 1;

  pinMode(incPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(decnPin, INPUT_PULLUP);

  attachInterrupt(incpPin, inc, FALLING);
  attachInterrupt(decPin, dec, FALLING);              
}

void loop() {}

void inc() {
  current_time = millis();
  if (current_time - previous_time > 200) { //debouncing for 0.2s
    mcp2515.sendMessage(&canMsg1);
  }
  previous_time = current_time;
}

void dec() {
  current_time = millis();
  if (current_time - previous_time > 200) { //debouncing for 0.2s
    mcp2515.sendMessage(&canMsg2);
  }
  previous_time = current_time;
}
```

receiver/reader of CAN massage

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <mcp2515.h>

struct can_frame canMsg1;
struct can_frame canMsg2;

MCP2515 mcp2515(10);

int pos = 0;
int up;
int down;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SPI.begin();

  mcp2515.reset();
  mcp2515.setBitrate(CAN_500KBPS, MCP_8MHZ);
  mcp2515.setNormalMode();      
}

void loop() {
  if (mcp2515.readMessage(&canMsg1) == MCP2515::ERROR_OK) { //read CAN increment button message
    if (canMsg1.can_id==0xAA) {
      up = canMsg1.data[0];
      if (up == LOW) {
        pos++;
      } else {}
    }      
  }

  if (mcp2515.readMessage(&canMsg2) == MCP2515::ERROR_OK) { //read CAN decrement button message
    if (canMsg2.can_id==0xBB) {
      down = canMsg2.data[0];
      if (down == LOW) {
        pos--;
      } else {}
    }      
  }
}
```

Comment: Regarding the button part, it is not recommended practice. Debouncing a button through an interrupt is more complex than regular debouncing (unless you have external hardware filters).

Comment: Instead making adjustment on hardware, can I just instead call another function from interrupt for debouncing and send canMsg? My guess is to make ISRs as short as possible(?)

Comment: You will get an interrupt per bounce, which is the problem. Here is an example how you can do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32647699/584518. But that's needlessly complex and therefore a bad design. Professional designs use periodic timers which read the GPIO, example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54900591/584518. Optionally with digital filters (median filters etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, your CAN events do not require any data.  But then, why do you set can_dlc to 1?  No data is 0 bytes.

You can try this:

Get rid of:

```
struct can_frame canMsg1;  // these only hog global memory for no practical use.
struct can_frame canMsg2;
```

Change your interrupt routines to:

```
void inc() {
  current_time = millis();
  if (current_time - previous_time > 200) { //debouncing for 0.2s
    mcp2515.beginPacket(0xAA);
    mcp2515.endPacket();
  }
  previous_time = current_time;
}

void dec() {
  current_time = millis();
  if (current_time - previous_time > 200) { //debouncing for 0.2s
    mcp2515.beginPacket(0xBB);
    mcp2515.endPacket();
  }
  previous_time = current_time;
}
```

I could not figure out what canMsg7 and canMsg8 were.  Nor why you'd need several message structures in global memory to receive one CAN message at a time...  I really don't think that's necessary.  Since your packets have no data, receiving gets streamlined as well:

```
int loop() {
    if (mcp2515.parsePacket() != 0) {  // != 0 => we have fully received a packet.
        switch (mcp2515.packetId()) {
           case 0xAA:
               // inc switch was pressed
               // ...
               break;

           case 0xBB:
               // dec switch was pressed
               // ...
               break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out canMsg7 and canMsg8, it's meant to be canMsg1/2, my bad lol. Also, I'm a bit lost here, especially `beginPacket` and `endPacked`. Could you please address some reference about that?

Comment: The API documentation is here:  https://github.com/sandeepmistry/arduino-CAN/blob/master/API.md.  That's the API I've used, It's simple to use: `beginPacket(id); write();` as needed, then `endPacket();` sends the whole thing.